# Combining/Stacking Columns from Select Result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have been searching for this all over, but unfortunately the real answer eludes me. I have a SELECT statement that returns three columns, similar to this basic example:

```
SELECT alpha, beta, gamma FROM table WHERE (...)
```

The WHERE clause is actually pretty hefty, so separating this into three separate SELECTs would probably be a bad idea. Now, this returns a table which looks something like this:

```
alpha | beta | gamma
----------------------
apple | (empty) | orange
banana | lemon | apple
```

What I would like to achieve however, is not the above result, but the following:

```
result
-------
apple
orange
banana
lemon
```

That is, the result columns from the previous SELECT statement are "stacked" or "combined" into one single column. The order is not important. Blank/missing/null fields are omitted and duplications (apple) are filtered, so the list contains unique values.

Technically, something along the lines of UNION would work, but UNION combines multiple SELECT statements. I want to combine the result columns from a single SELECT statement.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A trivial task if you do this at application level

Comment: What's wrong with using union?

Comment: Indeed. Still, I was primarily interested if there is some 'elegant' solution to this so as to avoid having to transform the result in the application. I was hoping to have missed out on something - but if there is no real solution, application level will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mitigate the overhead of a complex `where` statement being run with each of several `union` statements. The solution is to do the `union` on a simple statement and run the `where` over the result. In your example:

```
select distinct combined_col from (select alpha `combined_col` from table union select beta from table union select gamma from table) tab_alias where COMPLICATED_WHERE_STATEMENT;
```